# Angular material datepicker how to set timezone to UTC?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have already a datepicker with timezone +3hours with this config :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'date-picker',
  templateUrl: './date-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date-picker.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB' },
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS },
  ]
})
```

I would like it another way, so it would be +0hours of the given value.

Let's say i give datepicker this date : 2020-09-15:21:00 , and it converts to : 2020-09-16:00:00 (adds 3 hours), this is the problem now.

Comment: Utc dates have a z on the end. Zulu time

Answer (score 0):

You must set it as an additional provider:

```js
{provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: {useUtc: true}}
```

Comment: nothing changes, still getting +3 hours to actual date

Comment: That's funny it should have worked. Are you testing it on your computer or on some platform, like stackblitz?